# Booting to a black screen after BIOS reset

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, bios

I'm using an M3A79-T Deluxe motherboard on a PC. Recently did the following:

- Reset battery
- Reset jumpers
- Reset video card

Summary: I get asked to setup my BIOS. I do so, and then get a black screen where the monitor's light blinks and it sounds like things are happening even though nothing is. I switch off my PC, then boot it up again. I get asked to setup my BIOS again. Repeat.

Full story below in case it helps with pinpointing the problem:

- Put computer on sleep mode while compiling a program
- Attempted to wake it up an hour later
- It refused to wake no matter what--*sounded* like things were being processed but the screen was still black and it didn't look like anything had been loaded, monitor light blinking
- I shut it off via the power button
- Restarted it to find that it wouldn't boot up at all, giving me three short beeps
- Did the following: Removed and reset battery (did nothing), reset jumper (did nothing), took out video card and cleaned out the massive amount of dusk in its fan (computer finally booted up--kind of)
- Got a screen saying that I needed to either set up the bios or use the default config
- Conclusion after many tries with similar results:

  - Attempting to do setup myself and save the changes causes the computer to shut off, then turn on again in an extremely quiet way--the fans are running but nothing else is, and nothing starts up
  - Bypassing the setup screen and going with the defaults makes it shut down, *look* like it's booting up correctly, and then give me a black screen after the underscore screen
  - No matter what I pick, when I boot up again (after shutting down via power switch), it will give me that 'you need to setup' screen again
- I updated the BIOS. After the update was done I got that black screen again, so I shut down, and though the update was applied things did not get better
- I then reset all of the previously mentioned hardware in hopes that the second time would be the charm
- It wasn't

What might be the problem here? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: All the first indications before resetting where all about the video not re-initing out of standby.  3 beeps could mean the video is not initing. The twist here is the video (at least in compatability) comming up (i am guessing) everytime it is at defaults.  Something leads me to think you now have 1 more problem than when you started, and that is the cause of confusion.  Must check the clearing jumper with manuel be positive of the posistion, must check the battery connects if they are bent when moved.

Comment: Well you kinda have to have CPU some RAM, and the motherboard working somewhat to get the "failed" bios screen. You couldnt get a screen at all, if the video was not now working (some video). So your closest to operation, when it tosses a fail :-) (more confusion).  Potentially you could ignore that it is fully resetting back to defaults, because that could also be happening because it Cant Boot with the settings your making, and saved settings are not a requirement for analising the hardware all working, which it seems to be.

Comment: The next move to make when all this is happening, and all the hardware seems to be working sometimes. To set some of your BIOS/UEFI things lower, so it runs slower but at least all starts up. A Online guide on what changes what , or how to mess with things in that bios could be handy. Then you still have to achieve "boot" to an os, which is more settings that may have to be fully correct, or you get another Black screen, with the hardware all actually working , just not booting

Comment: Correction, Cant Post or cant boot, with the settings your making off of defaults.

Comment: @Psycogeek When I do the settings manually and then save them, it shuts down, and then doesn't start up again. Fans are spinning quietly but no actual boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it turned out that my video card was just dying. Got a new one, works perfectly--before that, I would need to do all of resetting the jumpers, battery, and video card before the computer would turn on *every time*.

Answer (score 0):

Is it giving any other errors like "cmos battery low" or anything else?

Things I would try:

- Try to boot from windows DVD/USB
- Put the video card in a different slot
- If possible, try a different video card
- If possible, try a different power supply